# What should I put in the meta-tag "google-site-verification" as a content?

Tags: html, meta-tags, google-search

I want to add the `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="..." />` to my personal project. I've already validated it in Google Search Console and it trowed me a token that I pasted it in the DNS server to complete this validation properly.

Now, what should I put in my **index.html** as a content property in the meta tag? I asume that it's not safe to copy that same token and put it in the `content=<TokenGivenByGoogle>` but what should I put instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google says to copy/paste this code to your HTML code, it is safe to do so.

However, if you already validated your property through DNS, you don't have to do it again in your HTML.